# Google Play Services rev 16 - any release/change notes or 'what's new' documents anywhere?

Tags: android

I've just installed the newly released Play Services extra for the SDK. This is now at revision 16. I remember that when rev 15 was released some extra methods were added to some classes.

I would like to know what has been added in revision 16. Can anyone tell me if a document describing the changes exits, and if so, where I might find it?

(A Google search for "Play Services" + "rev 16" produced nothing)

Comment: I do not understand the down vote or vote to close. This is a question directly relating to  programming using the Android SDK. It is not a 'please point me to a tutorial' type question. Will the voter please explain

Comment: I think the most detailed changelog you'll find is the post on the [Android Developers blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/03/google-play-services-43.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+blogspot%2FhsDu+%28Android+Developers+Blog%29).

Comment: @adneal - Thanks, that at least gives a pointer as to where to look. I still have rev 15, so by expanding the google-play-services.jar in Eclipse in each of the 'Private Libraries' it is possible if you expand every class!

Answer (score 1):

You can read about it at http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html

They discuss the new version 4.3 but SDK manager installs Rev. 16.  Google isn't very good at keeping numbers straight.  I'm trying to figure out if 4.3 is the same as rev 16.  I've looked around for some time now and I can't find anything.

Comment: The manifest for the official 16 release says version "4.3.23 (1069729-030)", build 4323030. Looks like they also bumped minSdkVersion from 8 to 9. I usually hang back a build since your app requires the device you run on to have a version of Google Play Services that is >= the the version of the lib you link with.

Comment: 4.3 references the GooglePlayServices apk version that the user downloads from the play store. That is different then the sdk version which we are using.